# Hudson and Maven. Packaging sources/resources to WEB-INF/src

Tags: maven-2, hudson, release

We are working with Maven and Hudson for unit testing and war building. Copying sources (java and resources) to WEB-INF/src is required by our customer.

There is a simple way to do this with maven?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be possible by declaring the `src/main/java` and `src/main/resources` as additional Web Resource directories in the [Maven War Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) configuration. Inspired by the [Adding and Filtering External Web Resources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) example:

```
    ...
    <configuration>
      <webResources>
        <resource>
          ...
        </resource>
        <resource>
          <directory>src/main/java</directory>
          <!-- override the destination directory for this resource -->
          <targetPath>WEB-INF/src</targetPath>
        </resource>
        <resource>
          <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
          <!-- override the destination directory for this resource -->
          <targetPath>WEB-INF/src</targetPath>
        </resource>
      </webResources>
    </configuration>
    ...
```